# Installing blender on another drive other than C:

Tags: windows, installation

i just got a new pc and found out it has 2 hard drives. one with my windows 10 OS (C:)(size: 149GB) and the other virtually blank (D:)(size: 1.67TB) my question is, will blender work if i install it on my D: drive or do i need to install it on my C: drive that has my OS on it?

Comment: not true. i want to install blender on my computer, but i want it to work. my concern is if i install it on my larger D: drive that it wont work or it wont work properly because my OS and system files are on my C: drive. ive never had more then one hard drive so i dont fully understand how it works. i dont know if the second, larger drive is strictly for storage or if i can run programs from it as well. i'm sorry if it seems off topic, but im very new to this and this is very much about installation of blender on my pc.

Comment: Yes, you can install Blender on  a drive other than C. I've used it on built in hard drives "C" and "D", both as installed, and from the Zip drive installer. I've also installed it on USB thumb drives, and microSD flash drives. Note though, that even though I install to a  "D", "F", "G"  ... drive, some bits of Blender always install in Windows to a directory with a name similar to "C:Users\your name\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\..."

Comment: I vote to keep the question open because it is about installation of Blender.

Comment: I think there is an issue with Unity, if you are using it as well, saving blender files into unity won't convert to fbx automatically if you are not installed in C drive.. but with the new versions.. maybe its a mute point.. im not sure any automatic conversion is happening now..

Comment: I am so very glad this q&a was still open so many months later.  It triggered the perfect answer for me.  Good work, people.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The anwser is YES you can! You can install any software on any of the drive you have. I have my 2nd harddisk on partition. So that means I have my physical harddisk virtually cut up into 3 portion. I have D:,E: and X:. I install all my program on X: and save all my data on E: , as my C: is an SSD with only 120GB of disk space.

As it happens Blender is no exception. In fact blender comes in Zip format flavor which does not even require any conventional installation at all.

**Note** Change your title to "Installing blender on another drive other than C:" at least it makes the question not sound like an OS one :) cheers.

Comment: You posted this 1 year 4 months ago and it is the perfect answer for what I needed.  i.e. ignore the .msi format in favor of the .zip - so I don't fill up my SSD.   Thank you!